# How to get CoreData fetch results into (multidimensional) arrays?

Tags: ios, core-data, multidimensional-array, eventkit

I want to get data from multiple rows in coredata into a multidimensional array so I can loop through them to create events in a calendar. However, it doesn't seem possible or advisable from an objects standpoint to have a true multidimensional array, so I've created one NSMutableArray per column of data I want to use for the event attributes (title, note, time of day).

But how do I assign all the values for each of the columns into its own NSMutableArray? Or should I use a NSDictionary to hold the values?

Here's my fetch from CoreData which is pretty standard:

```
    MyAppDelegate       *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];
NSFetchRequest         *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

NSEntityDescription    *entityDescription = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"My_List" 
                                                        inManagedObjectContext:context];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entityDescription];

NSSortDescriptor       *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"my_list_name" ascending:YES];
NSArray                *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];
[fetchRequest           setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
[fetchRequest           setFetchBatchSize:20];

[sortDescriptors        release];
[sortDescriptor         release];

NSFetchedResultsController *fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest
managedObjectContext:context
sectionNameKeyPath:nil
cacheName:@"my_list.cache"];

fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
NSError *error;
BOOL success = [fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error];
if (!success) {
    //Handle the error
}

self.resultsController = fetchedResultsController;

NSArray *fetchedObjects = [fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects];
```

Here I'm going speculate that I should loop through my NSManagedObject for each of the arrays but I'm not sure how.

```
  for (NSManagedObject *list in context) 
{
    [ reminderTitleMutableArray addObject:my_list_List.my_list_name ];
            [ reminderTitleMutableArray addObject:my_list_List.my_list_description ];
    [ reminderTitleMutableArray addObject:my_list_List.my_list_tminus ];
}
```

Is this the right way?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I strongly advise to not pursue this design pattern. By creating multiple or multidimensional arrays, you are cluttering your memory with data that is anyway stored in the core data persistent store. Memory problems are probable.

It would be much better to use some kind of `datasource` scheme, which I am sure you know from `UITableView`s, and retrieve the data for each date in your calendar as you need it. With a `fetchedResultsController` this is quite easy to achieve with `NSIndexPath`s or some other scheme suitable for your calendar.